# Selenium ChromeDriver => add bookmark

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Has anyone found a solid way to add a bookmark in chrome using the `ChromeDriver()` ??

Thus far, I've created two extension methods which I thought might work. Alas, neither do. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void CreateBookmark1(this IWebDriver webDriver)
{
    Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
    action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "d").Build().Perform();
}

public static void CreateBookmark2(this IWebDriver webDriver, string url, string name)
{
    var js = String.Format("window.external.AddFavorite('{0}', '{1}')", url, name);
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript(js);
}
```

I'm aware that `CreateBookmark2()` won't work due to certain javascript restrictions within the chrome stack. However, I had fully expected `CreateBookmark1()` to work as if the `CTRL+D` key combo had been pressed.

I'm also aware that for regression testing, this use-case would seldom be valid. However,  it's a key requirement of a demo that I'm putting together that the availability of this *feature* is present.

Any alternatives that achieve the same end result welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe access the [Chrome Bookmarks API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks).  Its is essentially an extension, so ChromeDriver should be able to interact with it via Driver.Manage() (I think)

Comment: +1  -thanks for this. this is exactly the kind of alternative that i've got no issue in investigating, tho of course it does introduce another moving part that presents an opportunity for failure - however, anything that can be automated and repeated is the goal here. just need to get my head into the space now... keep the ideas and alternatives coming tho (and would love to see a quick example of how this might patch together :-))